# I get this exception java.lang.IllegalStateException when I try to redirect to another page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have the following code :

1. util.library.mvc.Controller => Controller which extends from Servlet
2. modules.user.controllers.UpdateController => A Controller implementation

In the controller parent class I have a method wih the following content:

```
public void redirect(HttpServletResponse response, String url) 
        throws IOException
{
    response.sendRedirect(url);
}
```

But when I try to use it on my controller implementation gives me the following Exception:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

    UserRepository users = new UserRepository(request);
    User user = users.getUser(id);

            // My validation :
            if (user == null) {
                this.redirect("list"); // throws me an exception
            }

    request.setAttribute("user", user);
    request.setAttribute("action", "update");
    request.setAttribute("legend", "Update User");

    this.render(request, response, "/user/form");
}
```

I get the exception message in spanish but I translated it as follows:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: I can not forward after response has been carried out.
util.library.mvc.Controller.render(Controller.java:31)
modules.user.controllers.UpdateController.doGet(UpdateController.java:33)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

However when I use this method in this context :

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    User user = new User();
    user.populate(request);

    UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository(request);
    userRepository.update(user);

    this.redirect(response, "list");
}
```

It works fine.

Any help?

Comment: Let's get the full stack trace.

Comment: The exception clearly happens in the `render` method. Let's see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this if block

```
        if (user == null) {
            this.redirect("list"); // throws me an exception
        }
```

You forgot to put return here. due to that it redirects and than it is doing something in render and forwarding to another page.

so it should be

```
        if (user == null) {
            this.redirect("list"); // throws me an exception
            return;
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what a redirect is.

When you use

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

the Servlet container returns an HTTP response to the client with a 302 status code and a `Location` header pointing to the URI that the redirection should go to. In other words, you're telling the client to send a **new** GET request to the URI in the `Location` header.

Once the Servlet container has sent this HTTP response, response handling is done. If you attempt to do anything else with the `HttpServletResponse`, like forwarding to a JSP, you will get a bunch of exceptions.

When you forward to a JSP, you are expecting the Servlet container to render the content of the JSP and write it to the HTTP response, but with your `sendRedirect`, you've already sent the HTTP response. If you're redirecting, you cannot let that happen.

How you prevent it is up to you. [See Sanjeev's answer for one possibility.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22124107/438154)

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your code as follows

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

    UserRepository users = new UserRepository(request);
    User user = users.getUser(id);

            // My validation :
            if (user != null) {
                  request.setAttribute("user", user);
                  request.setAttribute("action", "update");
                  request.setAttribute("legend", "Update User");
                  this.render(request, response, "/user/form");
            } else {
                  this.redirect("list"); 
            }

}
```